# Open graph: showing user's timeline without any setting by user

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

My colleague and I have worked for Facebook Open Graph recently, and done today.
It works fine, but we have only one problem.

When user does something on our application, it appear Facebook's timeline automatically with this option 'Allowed on timeline'. So, user have to change it 'Shows on timeline' manually, then It appear one's timeline.

We already use 'publish_stream', it doesn't change anything. Is there any solution for this?